# how to make a .docx directory into a readable document after making adjustments to document.xml file

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to do some work on a document.xml file. I created a Word document which gave me the .docx file. I added the .zip extension and when I unarchived it, it become the document folder. In the document.xml, I could find the specific test that I was interested in ediging. I made some changes, closed file. I then archived and removed the .zip extension. Apple Pages wanted to open but both times, I got 'An unkown error occured' as output. Am I doing something wrong or is there some say to rectify?

thx

Comment: Works just fine for me, both in Office 2011 and Pages '09. Which changes have you made, exactly? What are you creating the Word document with?

Comment: Did you try unzipping / rezipping without doing any changes? What archive-program do you use for zipping. I know windows built-in zip works...

Comment: Hmm... I am using a mac and just using the default compression utility on it. Right-click -> 'compress'

Answer (score 0):

[This stackoverflow answer might do the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514052/how-to-zip-a-wordprocessingml-folder-into-readable-docx) if you happen to be opening this file up on a mac or linux machine.

The key is making the 'root' of the zip file the folder you unzipped.

From the command line, change directory into the unzipped folder.

> cd ./unzippped

Then

> zip -r ../rezipped.docx *

to zip it back up.